# Getting array values using map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I make this code return values instead of arrays? This is my representation, where the idea is to check whether IDs match between each other and get a `priceList` array of matching values. Can this be simplified, or perhaps replaced with `.reduce()`? Need extra help with this

```js
const priceList = options.map((productOption) => {
  const { data } = productOption;

  return data.filter(({ option_type_id, price }) => {
    if (selectedOptionsArray.indexOf(option_type_id) !== -1) {
      return price;
    }

    return 0;
  });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't understand, what you want to do, but `Array.prototype.map` always returns an array.

Comment: @ASDFGerte maybe OP means that they get nested arrays? in which case, `.map` -> `.flatMap`. But if it's something different, I'm not sure.

Comment: The callback of `.filter()` has to return a boolean. Why do you return an arbitrary number instead?

Comment: use `map` instead of `filter` you will get an array of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:
I have assumed few data (options and selectedOptionsArray)

Also there can be duplicate price in the priceList as multiple product can have same price. You can fix that by using Set:
`let uniqueItems = [...new Set(itemsArray)]`

```js
const options = [{
    data: [{
        option_type_id: 1,
        price: 100
    }, {
        option_type_id: 2,
        price: 200
    }]
}, {
    data: [{
        option_type_id: 3,
        price: 300
    }, {
        option_type_id: 4,
        price: 400
    }]
}]

const selectedOptionsArray = [1,3,4];

const priceList = options.flatMap((productOption) => productOption.data).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const { option_type_id, price } = currentValue;
    if (selectedOptionsArray.indexOf(option_type_id) !== -1) {
      return [...accumulator, price];
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
  
 console.log(priceList);
```